# unexpected structure when copying folders in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a set of projects that involve a mix of project-specific files plus common files. I'm trying to copy contents from two different folders -- a project-specific folder, and a common folder -- into a single folder named for the project. I also want to retain any folder hierarchies from the original folders.

For example, some paths to the common files:

```
src\Common\PackageAssets\logo1.jpg
src\Common\PackageAssets\logo2.jpg
```

And example paths to project-specific files:

```
src\Projects\ProjectA\PackageFiles\readme.txt
src\Projects\ProjectA\PackageFiles\scale-100\projA.png
```

The desired result after copying would be:

```
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\logo1.png
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\logo2.png
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\readme.txt
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\scale-100\projA.png
```

What I'm using is this:

```
[string]$pkgContentPath = "bld\$project\pkgFiles"

# copy common files
Copy-Item -Path .\src\Common\PackageAssets -Recurse -Destination $pkgContentPath
# copy project-specific files
Copy-Item -Path .\src\Projects\ProjectA\PackageFiles\ -Recurse -Destination $pkgContentPath
```

But instead of the expected results, all the files are ending up in an extra level of subfolder:

```
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\PackageAssets\logo1.png
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\PackageAssets\logo2.png
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\PackageFiles\readme.txt
bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles\PackageFiles\scale-100\projA.png
```

I'm stumped. I can't figure out how to get rid of the extra subfolder layer. I tried using Get-ChildItem piping to Copy-Item, but then the subfolder hierarchies were lost.

In a .bat file, this works:

```
xcopy src\Common\PackageAssets\* bld\%project\pkg_contents /s
xcopy src\Projects\%project\PackageFiles bld\%project\pkg_contents /s
```

I guess I could use xcopy, but surely there must be a way to do this using cmdlets.

Comment: `New-Item bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles -Type Directory; Copy-Item -Path .\src\Common\PackageFile\* bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles -Recurse; Copy-Item -Path .\src\Projects\ProjectA\PackageFiles\* bld\ProjectA\pkgFiles -Recurse`

Comment: What else is odd is that results are different when I'm running commands in the console versus from a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is a **[known problem](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2934)** as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.2.0-preview.2, unfortunately:

In short, the **behavior of `Copy-Item` regrettably depends on whether the target directory happens to exist already or not**:

**If the target dir. exists, it is not the source directory's *content* that is copied, but the source dir. *as a whole*, to a *subdirectory*** of the target directory named for the source dir.

---

The **workaround** is already mostly spelled out in [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)'s helpful comment on the question:

- Before copying, make sure that the target directory exists.
- Append `\*` to the source path to explicitly target the *contents* of the source dir.

  - Also specify `-Force`, so as to ensure that *hidden* files and directories are also copied.

```
$pkgContentPath = "bld\$project\pkg_contents"

# Make sure the target dir. exists.
# (-Force leaves an existing dir alone and otherwise creates it.)
New-Item -Force -Type Directory $pkgContentPath

# IF desired, clear out the pre-existing directory content.
# !! Beware of Remove-Item's intermittent failures - see below.
#  Remove-Item -Force $pkgContentPath\* -Recurse.

# Copy with \* appended to the source paths and -Force added:
#
# copy common files
Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Path .\src\Common\PackageAssets\* $pkgContentPath
# copy project-specific files
Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Path .\src\Projects\ProjectA\PackageFiles\* $pkgContentPath
```

A note re use of `Remove-Item -Recurse` to clear out preexisting destination-directory content, if needed: Regrettably, `Remove-Item` can *fail* on occasion and you cannot predict when that happens - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375) for a robust alternative.

Comment: In my case, I already had the target folder created, and was still having problems. However, I didn't have \* appended, and that did make the difference.