# Cannot remove item, The Directory is not empty

Tags: windows, powershell

When using the `Remove-Item` command, even utilizing the `-r` and `-Force` parameters, sometimes the following error message is returned:

> Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Test Folder\Test Folder\Target: The directory is not empty.

Particularly, this happens when the directory to be removed is opened in Windows Explorer.

Now, while it is possible to avoid this simply by having Windows Explorer closed or not browsing that location, I work my scripts in a multi-user environment where people sometimes just forget to close Windows Explorer windows, I am interested in a solution for deleting entire folders and directories even if they are opened in Windows Explorer.

Is there an option more powerful than `-Force` that I can set to achieve this?

To reliably reproduce this, create the folder `C:\Test Folder\Origin` and populate it with some files and subfolders (important), then take the following script or one like it and execute it once. Now open one of the subfolders of `C:\Test Folder\Target` (in my case, I used `C:\Test Folder\Target\Another Subfolder` containing `A third file.txt`), and try running the script again. You will now get the error. If  you run the script a third time, you will not get the error again (depending on circumstances that I have yet to determine, though, the error sometimes occurs the second time and then never again, and at other times it occurs *every* second time).

```
$SourcePath =  "C:\Test Folder\Origin"
$TargetPath =  "C:\Test Folder\Target"

if (Test-Path $TargetPath) {
    Remove-Item -r $TargetPath -Force
}
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TargetPath 

Copy-Item $SourcePath -Destination $TargetPath -Force -Recurse -Container
```

Comment: With what you're actually doing you could look into xcopy.

Answer (score 34):

*Update*: **Starting with (at least <sup>[1]</sup>) Windows 10 version `20H2`** (I don't know that Windows *Server*  version and build that corresponds to; run `winver.exe` to check your version and build), the **[`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew) Windows API function now exhibits *synchronous* behavior** on supported file-systems, including NTFS, which **implicitly solves the  problems with PowerShell's `Remove-Item` and .NET's `System.IO.File.Delete` / `System.IO.Directory.Delete` (but, curiously, *not* with `cmd.exe`'s `rd /s`).**

---

This is **ultimately only a *timing* issue**: the last handle to a subdirectory may not be closed yet at the time an attempt is made to the delete the parent directory - and this is a **fundamental problem**, not restricted to having File Explorer windows open:

Incredibly, **the Windows file and directory removal API is *asynchronous***: that is, by the time the function call returns, it is not guaranteed that removal has *completed yet*.

Regrettably, **`Remove-Item` fails to account for that** - and neither do `cmd.exe`'s `rd /s` and .NET's `[System.IO.Directory]::Delete()` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508169/45375) for details.
This results in ***intermittent, unpredictable* failures.**

The **workaround** comes courtesy of in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/uhRWMGBjlO8?t=455) (starts at 7:35), a PowerShell implementation of which is below:

---

**Synchronous directory-removal function `Remove-FileSystemItem`**:

**Important:**

- The synchronous custom implementation is only required on *Windows*, because the file-removal system calls on Unix-like platforms are synchronous to begin with. Therefore, the function simply defers to `Remove-Item` on Unix-like platforms. On Windows, the custom implementation:

  - **requires that the *parent* directory of a directory being removed be *writable*** for the synchronous custom implementation to work.
  - is also applied when deleting directories on any *network drives*.
- **What will NOT prevent reliable removal:**

  - File Explorer, at least on Windows 10, does *not* lock directories it displays, so it won't prevent removal.
  - PowerShell doesn't lock directories either, so having another PowerShell window whose current location is the target directory or one of its subdirectories won't prevent removal (by contrast, `cmd.exe` *does* lock - see below).
  - Files opened with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` / `[System.IO.FileShare]::Delete` (which is rare) in the target directory's subtree also won't prevent removal, though they do live on under a temporary name in the parent directory until the last handle to them is closed.
- **What WILL prevent removal**:

  - If there's a **permissions problem** (if ACLs prevent removal), removal is aborted.
  - If an indefinitely ***locked* file** or directory is encountered, removal is aborted. Notably, that includes:

    - `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt), unlike PowerShell, *does* lock the directory that is its current directory, so if you have a `cmd.exe` window open whose current directory is the target directory or one of its subdirectories, removal will *fail*.
    - If an application keeps a file open in the target directory's subtree that was *not* opened with file-sharing mode `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` / `[System.IO.FileShare]::Delete` (using this mode is rare), removal will fail. Note that this only applies to applications that *keep files open* while working with their content.  (e.g., Microsoft Office applications), whereas text editors such as Notepad and Visual Studio Code, by contrast, do *not* keep they've loaded open.
- Hidden files and files with the read-only attribute:

  - These are *quietly removed*; in other words: this function **invariably behaves like `Remove-Item -Force`**.
  - Note, however, that in order to target hidden files / directories as *input*, you must specify them as *literal* paths, because they won't be found via a wildcard expression.
- The reliable custom implementation on Windows comes at the cost of decreased performance.

```
function Remove-FileSystemItem {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Removes files or directories reliably and synchronously.

  .DESCRIPTION
    Removes files and directories, ensuring reliable and synchronous
    behavior across all supported platforms.

    The syntax is a subset of what Remove-Item supports; notably,
    -Include / -Exclude and -Force are NOT supported; -Force is implied.
    
    As with Remove-Item, passing -Recurse is required to avoid a prompt when 
    deleting a non-empty directory.

    IMPORTANT:
      * On Unix platforms, this function is merely a wrapper for Remove-Item, 
        where the latter works reliably and synchronously, but on Windows a 
        custom implementation must be used to ensure reliable and synchronous 
        behavior. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8211

    * On Windows:
      * The *parent directory* of a directory being removed must be 
        *writable* for the synchronous custom implementation to work.
      * The custom implementation is also applied when deleting 
         directories on *network drives*.

    * If an indefinitely *locked* file or directory is encountered, removal is aborted.
      By contrast, files opened with FILE_SHARE_DELETE / 
      [System.IO.FileShare]::Delete on Windows do NOT prevent removal, 
      though they do live on under a temporary name in the parent directory 
      until the last handle to them is closed.

    * Hidden files and files with the read-only attribute:
      * These are *quietly removed*; in other words: this function invariably
        behaves like `Remove-Item -Force`.
      * Note, however, that in order to target hidden files / directories
        as *input*, you must specify them as a *literal* path, because they
        won't be found via a wildcard expression.

    * The reliable custom implementation on Windows comes at the cost of
      decreased performance.

  .EXAMPLE
    Remove-FileSystemItem C:\tmp -Recurse

    Synchronously removes directory C:\tmp and all its content.
  #>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='Medium', DefaultParameterSetName='Path', PositionalBinding=$false)]
    param(
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
      [string[]] $Path
      ,
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Literalpath', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
      [Alias('PSPath')]
      [string[]] $LiteralPath
      ,
      [switch] $Recurse
    )
    begin {
      # !! Workaround for https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1759
      if ($ErrorActionPreference -eq [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Ignore) { $ErrorActionPreference = 'Ignore'}
      $targetPath = ''
      $yesToAll = $noToAll = $false
      function trimTrailingPathSep([string] $itemPath) {
        if ($itemPath[-1] -in '\', '/') {
          # Trim the trailing separator, unless the path is a root path such as '/' or 'c:\'
          if ($itemPath.Length -gt 1 -and $itemPath -notmatch '^[^:\\/]+:.$') {
            $itemPath = $itemPath.Substring(0, $itemPath.Length - 1)
          }
        }
        $itemPath
      }
      function getTempPathOnSameVolume([string] $itemPath, [string] $tempDir) {
        if (-not $tempDir) { $tempDir = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($itemPath) }
        [IO.Path]::Combine($tempDir, [IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
      }
      function syncRemoveFile([string] $filePath, [string] $tempDir) {
        # Clear the ReadOnly attribute, if present.
        if (($attribs = [IO.File]::GetAttributes($filePath)) -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly) {
          [IO.File]::SetAttributes($filePath, $attribs -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly)
        }
        $tempPath = getTempPathOnSameVolume $filePath $tempDir
        [IO.File]::Move($filePath, $tempPath)
        [IO.File]::Delete($tempPath)
      }
      function syncRemoveDir([string] $dirPath, [switch] $recursing) {
          if (-not $recursing) { $dirPathParent = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($dirPath) }
          # Clear the ReadOnly attribute, if present.
          # Note: [IO.File]::*Attributes() is also used for *directories*; [IO.Directory] doesn't have attribute-related methods.
          if (($attribs = [IO.File]::GetAttributes($dirPath)) -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly) {
            [IO.File]::SetAttributes($dirPath, $attribs -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly)
          }
          # Remove all children synchronously.
          $isFirstChild = $true
          foreach ($item in [IO.directory]::EnumerateFileSystemEntries($dirPath)) {
            if (-not $recursing -and -not $Recurse -and $isFirstChild) { # If -Recurse wasn't specified, prompt for nonempty dirs.
              $isFirstChild = $false
              # Note: If -Confirm was also passed, this prompt is displayed *in addition*, after the standard $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess() prompt.
              #       While Remove-Item also prompts twice in this scenario, it shows the has-children prompt *first*.
              if (-not $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue("The item at '$dirPath' has children and the -Recurse switch was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?", 'Confirm', ([ref] $yesToAll), ([ref] $noToAll))) { return }
            }
            $itemPath = [IO.Path]::Combine($dirPath, $item)
            ([ref] $targetPath).Value = $itemPath
            if ([IO.Directory]::Exists($itemPath)) {
              syncremoveDir $itemPath -recursing
            } else {
              syncremoveFile $itemPath $dirPathParent
            }
          }
          # Finally, remove the directory itself synchronously.
          ([ref] $targetPath).Value = $dirPath
          $tempPath = getTempPathOnSameVolume $dirPath $dirPathParent
          [IO.Directory]::Move($dirPath, $tempPath)
          [IO.Directory]::Delete($tempPath)
      }
    }

    process {
      $isLiteral = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'LiteralPath'
      if ($env:OS -ne 'Windows_NT') { # Unix: simply pass through to Remove-Item, which on Unix works reliably and synchronously
        Remove-Item @PSBoundParameters
      } else { # Windows: use synchronous custom implementation
        foreach ($rawPath in ($Path, $LiteralPath)[$isLiteral]) {
          # Resolve the paths to full, filesystem-native paths.
          try {
            # !! Convert-Path does find hidden items via *literal* paths, but not via *wildcards* - and it has no -Force switch (yet)
            # !! See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6501
            $resolvedPaths = if ($isLiteral) { Convert-Path -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $rawPath } else { Convert-Path -ErrorAction Stop -path $rawPath}
          } catch {
            Write-Error $_ # relay error, but in the name of this function
            continue
          }
          try {
            $isDir = $false
            foreach ($resolvedPath in $resolvedPaths) {
              # -WhatIf and -Confirm support.
              if (-not $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($resolvedPath)) { continue }
              if ($isDir = [IO.Directory]::Exists($resolvedPath)) { # dir.
                # !! A trailing '\' or '/' causes directory removal to fail ("in use"), so we trim it first.
                syncRemoveDir (trimTrailingPathSep $resolvedPath)
              } elseif ([IO.File]::Exists($resolvedPath)) { # file
                syncRemoveFile $resolvedPath
              } else {
                Throw "Not a file-system path or no longer extant: $resolvedPath"
              }
            }
          } catch {
            if ($isDir) {
              $exc = $_.Exception
              if ($exc.InnerException) { $exc = $exc.InnerException }
              if ($targetPath -eq $resolvedPath) {
                Write-Error "Removal of directory '$resolvedPath' failed: $exc"
              } else {
                Write-Error "Removal of directory '$resolvedPath' failed, because its content could not be (fully) removed: $targetPath`: $exc"
              }
            } else {
              Write-Error $_  # relay error, but in the name of this function
            }
            continue
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>[1] I've personally verified that the issue is resolved in version `20H2`, by running the tests in [GitHub issue #27958](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27958) for hours without failure; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512798/45375) suggests that the problem was resolved as early as version `1909`, starting with build `18363.657`, but [Dinh Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125534/dinh-tran) finds that the issue is *not* resolved as of build `18363.1316` when removing large directory trees such as `node_modules`. I couldn't find any official information on the subject.</sup>

Comment: I've updated to Windows 20H2 and this issue actually gone for good. deleted the ```node_moodules``` sucessfully without no extra workaround. Now I'll have to wait for window server updates only :)