# File System Object : MoveFolder gives random "Permission Denied" Errors

Tags: powershell, filesystemobject

I'm using the file system object in Powershell in order to do some folder cycling: let's say having oldFolder, currentFolder and newFolder, this is the process:

1. DeleteFolder oldFolder
2. MoveFolder currentFolder to oldFolder
3. MoveFolder newFolder to currentFolder

When running in script, step 2 or 3 randomly throws CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED.
When the script stops, I repeat the last command and it finishes correctly.

Seems as if the MoveFolder method works semi asynchronous.

ps: the folders have subfolders and a lot of files

I've tried adding some delay, but I'm not happy not knowing what is happening.

```
$oldFolder = "D:\test\folder_OLD"
$curFolder = "D:\test\folder"
$newFolder = "D:\test\folder_NEW"

$fso = $fso = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject

if (Test-Path $oldFolder) {$fso.DeleteFolder($oldFolder)}

if (Test-Path $curFolder) {$fso.MoveFolder($curFolder,$oldFolder)}

$fso.MoveFolder($newFolder,$curFolder)
```

Comment: have you tried using pure powershell instead of mixing wscript with PoSh? [*grin*]

Comment: Surprisingly and unfortunately, [directory (folder) removal is inherently asynchronous on Windows](https://serverfault.com/a/942429/176094), which causes intermittent, unpredictable failures. I suspect that's what's happening here; for a robust custom folder-removal function, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: The problem is ultimately the Windows API, and PowerShell's `Remove-Item -Recurse` is equally affected, as is `cmd.exe`'s `rd /s`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, yeah, that it only happens intermittently is part of the problem; apparently there's talk about making the Windows API synchronous soon: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33603#issuecomment-466595889

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the swift responses. That confirms my suspicion.

I'll try to use another method, maybe pure powershell as proposed by Lee.