# Rimraf - powershell script glob syntax

Tags: powershell, glob

I want to use rimraf command in powershell script to delete all files and sub-folders in certain directory (named "Results"). I am testing rimraf on virtual drive ("B") and need to use network path, so my command looks like `rimraf '\\PC name\B\Results\*'` , but it does nothing and I can´t figure out the correct syntax. I´ve tried many different variations of the path, but none was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) Node.js module and CLI normally *does* perform its own globbing on Windows, so - given that argument `'\\PC name\B\Results\*'`, as a verbatim string, is passed *unmodified* to `rimraf`, the implication is that `rimraf` somehow doesn't support globbing on your `.vhd` drive.

Note: The `-G` command-line option *disables* globbing, but it is enabled by default.

The **workaround is to let *PowerShell* do the globbing**.

The following *should* work, but doesn't as of `rimraf` v3.0.2 / Node.js v14.15.12:

```
# !! Currently does NOT work - even though it should.
# CAVEAT: INSTANTLY DELETES ALL CONTENT IN THE TARGET DIR.
rimraf -G (Get-Item '\\PC name\B\Results\*' -Force).FullName
```

Seemingly, passing *multiple* paths (the `Get-Item` call results in an *array* of file/directory names whose elements are passed as individual arguments) is currently broken.

Therefore, **use the following**, which, however, is slow, because `rimraf` is invoked separately for each file and directory:

```
# Should work, but is slow.
# CAVEAT: INSTANTLY DELETES ALL CONTENT IN THE TARGET DIR.
(Get-Item '\\PC name\B\Results\*' -Force).FullName | % { rimraf -G $_ }
```

Of course, **you can also use PowerShell's own [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) cmdlet**:

```
# CAVEAT: If you remove -WhatIf, instantly deletes all content in the target dir.
Remove-Item '\\PC name\B\Results\*' -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

Note that, irrespective of the tool used for deletion, deleting *directory subtrees* on Windows versions before Windows 10 20H2 can fail intermittently, due to the previously asynchronous behavior of file deletion - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information and your solution!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @JakubDlabka; my pleasure.