# Error: Illegal characters in path in npm rimraf

Tags: windows, npm, windows-10, npx

I am getting an error while I tried to delete multiple directories using npm rimraf.

> Error: Illegal characters in path

Command I run is `rimraf **/lib/**`

```
> ecommerce.ui@0.7.2 clean-libs
> rimraf **/lib/**

Error: Illegal characters in path.
    at pathArg (C:\Users\SUDARANGA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.9.0\node_modules\rimraf\dist\cjs\src\path-arg.js:45:33)
    at C:\Users\SUDARANGA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.9.0\node_modules\rimraf\dist\cjs\src\index.js:34:66       
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\SUDARANGA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.9.0\node_modules\rimraf\dist\cjs\src\index.js:34:28       
    at main (C:\Users\SUDARANGA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.9.0\node_modules\rimraf\dist\cjs\src\bin.js:134:11) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SUDARANGA\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.9.0\node_modules\rimraf\dist\cjs\src\bin.js:143:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12) {
  path: 'C:\\source\\Ecommerce.UI\\**\\lib\\**',
  code: 'EINVAL'
}
```

Comment: no glob starting from v4, in Windows you can use powershell, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65580201/1207195

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Version 4.0 of `rimraf` removed globbing support, but they restored globbing in version 4.2 (released March 2023).

If you're using `rimraf` from the command line (i.e. using it as an npm command and not using the JavaScript API), it's now behind a `--glob` flag:

```
rimraf --glob packages/**/*.tgz
```

If you're using the JavaScript API, you can use the `glob` option:

```js
import { rimrafSync } from 'rimraf';

rimrafSync('/foo/*.bar', { glob: true });
```

If you can't use version 4.2, and you're using `rimraf` just from the command line, then I've found that [`del-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del-cli) seems to be a good cross-platform replacement.