# How do I automatically answer “yes” in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How do I automatically answer “yes” to a prompt in Powershell?

```
Write-Host "Deleting all files and subfolders..."
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\333\Downloads -Recurse | Remove-Item
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\333\Desktop -Recurse | Remove-Item
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\333\Documents -Recurse | Remove-Item
Clear-RecycleBin -Force
Write-Host "Done!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order **to avoid a confirmation prompt when using [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) to delete a *non-empty directory***:

- you need the **`-Recurse`** switch
- additionally, **if the directory contains *hidden* items**, you need the **`-Force`** switch.
- (If the [`$ConfirmPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#confirmpreference) has been changed from its default, `'High'`, you'll *also* need `-Confirm:$false`)

In short:

- `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $someDirectory` quietly removes directory `$someDirectory` *itself* (invariably with all its contents)
- `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $someDirectory\*` removes just its *contents* (along with any subdirectories, recursively).

*Caveat*: In earlier Windows versions, before  Windows 10 20H2, file removal is inherently *asynchronous*, which means that such recursive calls *sometimes* fail - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375).

---

Therefore, you don't even need `Get-ChildItem` in your case - just use `Remove-Item` to remove the *content* of the target directories, (which includes an *subdirectories*) - by appending [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) `\*` - which you can even do with a *single* call, given that *arrays* of input paths are supported.

In the context of your original code:

```bash
Write-Host "Deleting all files and subfolders..."
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path C:\Users\333\Downloads\*, C:\Users\333\Desktop\*, C:\Users\333\Documents\* 
Clear-RecycleBin -Force
Write-Host "Done!"
```