# What is the use of -recurse in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Sorry it's probably a dumb question: what is the difference between

`Remove-Item -recurse -Force -Verbose` and `Remove-Item -Force -Verbose`

it seems if we use `-recurse` for a folder and subfolders powershell delete file one by one inside the folder. and if we remove the `-recurse` powershell simply delete the main folder without checking inside the folder. technically isn't script will run faster without `-recurse`?

Comment: if you DO NOT use `-Recurse` in that situation, you usually get a confirmation request ... well, it has every time that i have tired it.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you should make that an answer as it is correct using default PowerShell settings on Windows 10 (at least). If a directory does contain data you will get a prompt to ask if you're sure.

Comment: @Seth - i am unsure of when something reaches Answer quality ... but i will take your recommendation and go with that. thank you! [*grin*]

Comment: The command has to recursively delete all files and sub folders before being able to delete the specified directory in any case, even if you don't specify `-recurse`. Only empty directories can actually be deleted (at the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-removedirectoryw) level).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `Remove-Item` on a dir tree that holds files ... and do NOT use `-Recurse`, you will get the standard confirmation prompt. so using that parameter makes it run without the delay from the "do you really want to do this?" prompt.

this is one of the reasons that some folks prefer to pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to `Remove-Item`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on possible advantages of using `Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item` over `Remove-Item -Recurse`?

Comment: Here is a link to a Scripting guy article of about twelve years ago,  illustrating the use of Get-childItem -recurse in conjunction with Remove-Item.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-delete-all-files-from-nested-folders-and-subfolders/

Comment: `Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item` per se doesn't necessarily help, if you don't use `-Recurse`: If `Get-ChildItem`'s output is / includes a nonempty _directory_, you'll get the confirmation prompt too. If the intent is to delete _files_ only, `Get-ChildItem -File | Remove-Item` does help, however, in cases where `Remove-Item *` or `Remove-Item *.foo` could unintentionally match _directories_ too (`Remove-Item` has _no_ `-File` (or `-Directory`) switch, which is arguably a shortcoming). /cc @zett42

Comment: @mklement0 - good point ... i made that a tad clearer by adding `-Recurse` to the `G-CI`  call.

Comment: @zett42 - the purpose of piping `G-CI` to `R-I` is that [when you include `-Recurse` on the `G-CI` call] you are _explicitly_ dealing with individual items. that is a somewhat more direct representation of how some of us think about the operation. **_that "concept to code" match up makes for easier coding & easier debugging & easier maintenance._**

Comment: Adding `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem` doesn't help, however, because without `-File` it can still potentially include _nonempty directories_, which - without `-Recurse` applied to `Remove-Item` - again triggers the confirmation prompt.

Comment: @mklement0 - ah! i have never run into that situation. thank you for the info! [*grin*]

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**

**Pass *both* `-Recurse` *and* `-Force` to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)  in order to (more) predictably delete (remove) a given folder**, which - barring any permission and timing problems - **deletes the folder *and any contents*** it may have.

**Caveat**: This *instantly* deletes any contents inside the target folder, and, given that deleted items are *not* placed in the operating system's recycle bin, can only be recovered, potentially, with specialty software.

---

> it seems if we use `-recurse` for a folder and subfolders powershell delete file one by one inside the folder.

More accurately, it deletes the target folder's *subtree*, i.e. it recursively deletes *all files and subfolders located in the target folder, including *their* files and subfolders*, recursively, before deleting the target folder *itself*. In effect, it deletes the target folder *and all of its contents*, if any, but note the *caveats*:

- re "protected" items, which additionally require `-Force`, discussed below.
- re intermittent failures due to the file-system APIs being *asynchronous* in older Windows versions, discussed in the bottom section.

In fact, **deleting all the *contents* of a folder before deleting the folder itself is the *only* way to delete a *nonempty* folder, technically**: the file-system APIs do *not* offer deletion of a nonempty folder *as a single operation*.

Because inadvertently deleting an entire subfolder tree can have disastrous consequences, as a safety mechanism **PowerShell requires you to signal the intent to delete a *nonempty* folder *explicitly* - by passing `-Recurse`**.

- **If you neglect to pass `-Recurse` and the target folder is nonempty, you get an *interactive confirmation prompt* - irrespective of whether `-Force` is specified or not**. Choose `[A] Yes to All` (type `a`) to delete the folder and all its contents - but see the situational additional need for `-Force` below.

That said, you *do* also need `-Force` in order to (more) *predictably* remove a nonempty target folder, because **`-Force` makes PowerShell also delete "protected" files and folders, which are *hidden* files and folders and files that have the `ReadOnly` and/or `System` attributes set** (on Windows).

- **If you neglect to pass `-Force` when you use `-Recurse` or interactively choose `[A] Yes to All` in response to the confirmation prompt, the presence of *at least one protected item* will *prevent* removal of the target folder as a whole**, though *unprotected* items inside the subtree *will* get deleted right away.
- Each protected item will cause a non-terminating error to be emitted, concluded by a non-terminating error that the target folder cannot be removed, because it isn't empty (yet). Perhaps confusingly, in *Windows PowerShell* the per-protected-item error messages only talks about "[in]sufficient access rights", even though the real problem in this case isn't one of *permissions*; the error message has been amended in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) to explicitly mention hidden, system, and readonly items.

> if we remove the `-recurse` powershell simply delete the main folder without checking inside the folder.

No: It follows from the above that **you cannot delete a given nonempty folder *unless you delete its contents first***.

If you attempt that without `-Recurse`, you'll invariably get the confirmation prompt (or, in non-interactive scenarios, the call will *fail* outright).

> technically isn't script will run faster without `-recurse`?

It also follows from the above that **only an *empty* folder can be removed *without* `-Recurse` without triggering the confirmation prompt**.

If you *do* also specify `-Recurse` when targeting an empty folder, *hypothetically* unnecessary work of testing whether child items exist could be performed. In practice, `Remove-Item`'s implementation *always* performs this test, whether or not you pass `-Recurse`.

---

**Even with both `-Recurse` and `-Force` specified, overall removal may *fail***:

- ... due to **insufficient file-system permission** held by the current user relative to the target folder and its contents.
- ... ***intermittently*, due to running on Windows versions *older than Windows 10 20H2*** (I don't know that Windows *Server* version that corresponds to), because **file-system item deletion there was inherently *asynchronous*(!)**, resulting in *intermittent* failure to fully delete a given target folder, namely if deletion of an item *inside* the folder hadn't completed yet by the time deletion of the folder itself was attempted: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375) for details and a workaround.

Comment: Glad to hear they were helpful, @Shahpari.