# How can I make my PowerShell script wait for the first command to finish and then run the second command

Tags: windows, powershell, node-modules

I have this PowerShell script that I want to run for my angular project.
I can only get it to run the first command or I can only get it to run the first command and then immediately run the second command.

```
Start /wait /b   rmdir  node_modules /S
 
 Start npm install /b /wait
```

I've looked on stack overflow and googled different stuff and have seen some good suggestions but haven't been able to get it to work correctly.  It does currently run the first command and then finish.

I've tried to remove some of the parameters like /b or /S with no luck.

Comment: `Remove-Item node_modules -Force -Recurse; Start-Process npm install -Wait`

Comment: If you need an answer in general (unrelated to npm) then a solution is to write your own function to invoke process, process class has `WaitForExit` which let's you wait for process to finish, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0

Comment: Why are you using `Start`(`-Process`) at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your primary problem is that **you're using syntax for *`cmd.exe`*'s internal `start` and `rmdir` commands, which doesn't work in PowerShell**.

  - While PowerShell does have commands with the same names, they're *aliases* of PowerShell *cmdlets*, [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) and [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item), and therefore require *different syntax*.
- While you could fix your `Start` commands to use **`Start-Process`** instead, there's **no reason to use it** to begin with, given that invoking cmdlets and (console) programs *directly* executes them *synchronously*, in the *same console window*, with the output streams connected to PowerShell's, *by default*.

Therefore:

```bash
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse node_modules  # Equivalent of rmdir /S /Q node_modules
npm install
```

Note: In older versions of Windows, including versions of Windows 10 prior to release 20H2, file and directory removal is inherently *asynchronous*, so on occasion the removal may not have fully completed yet by the time `Remove-Item` returns; it seems that calling via `cmd /c` - `cmd /c rmdir /S /Q node_modules` - lessens the chances of that happening (but still doesn't fully eliminate the problem). A reliable workaround is far from trivial, unfortunately - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375).

---

**Update**: As it turns out, you were actually running a *batch file* (`.cmd` or `.bat`), not a PowerShell script (`.ps1`), but the above points apply analogously; the **batch-file solution** is:

```bash
rmdir /S /Q node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you i changed Remove-Item to rmdir because it was a syntax error but other than that this solution worked great.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @RedProject. If the `Remove-Item` call caused a syntax error and `rmdir` worked _without `cmd /c`_, the implication is that you're running a _batch file_ (`.cmd` or `.bat`), not a PowerShell script (`.ps1`).

Comment: Thanks sorry for the miscommunication.